# What does this quote of Elizabeth Gaskell mean?

Tags: writing, quotes, books

> How easy it is to judge rightly after one sees what evil comes from judging wrongly!
> -*Elizabeth Gaskell*

Comment: We need more context, to narrow the application, because it seems a foolish saying if applied generally. (If you had just seen a fellow aerialist bite the sawdust and die, would that render easier the judgment of when to let go the trapeze?)

Comment: @Brian Donovan When to let go the trapeze act.

Answer (score 1):

It is a generality. Gaskell is saying much the same as the contemporary “Hindsight is the only exact science”. Once we perceive the consequence of our mistakes it is easy to see how we could have avoided them.